# Push Unique Array in Object | Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i would like to push unique Array into an Object using the key **Name**

i tried this code but still not working. Any help ? Thank you !

```
addArray(){
  if (!this.sessions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
  this.sessions.push(this.item);
  }
},
```

Comment: Is this.sessions an array or an object?

Answer (score -1):

```
this.sessions.push(this.item);
```

This line means that sessions is an array. So if you want to push unique objects with key Name into sessions array you can check below:

```
    addIntoArray(yourNewlyAddedObject){
        var is_in = false;
        this.sessions.forEach(function (session) {
            if (session.Name === yourNewlyAddedObject.Name) is_in = true;
        });
        return is_in;
    },
```

Check new item with `addIntoArray(obj)` function. If this function return true then this means the currently added object key "Name" is already in array. Else it returns false.  So add this object to sessions array if current object with key Name if not exist in array (when function returns false).